# python using wald test to test the predictors significance

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I need to do logistic regression for some data, I have obtained some user features such as their `post` `types`, `number of friends`, `number of posts`, `number of uploaded photos` and etc, and have clustered these  users into several clusters, now, I want to do wald test to test which predictors (from these user features) are significant for predicting the cluster these users belong to, using binary logistic regression, for example, for users in cluster 1, if the user belongs to `cluster 1`, the `cluster_label` is `1`, and other users' `cluster_label` is `zero`, I need to use wald_test to choose which predictors are significant for predicting the cluster label, for example, for predicting users in cluster 1, by doing wald test, the number of friends and the number of uploaded photos have the highest wald score, therefore, these two features are significant for predicting users cluster type in cluster 1; maybe for users who are in cluster 2, by doing wald test, the number of posts and the number of shared news are significant for predicting these users cluster label

the `pandas` dataframe of these data are illustrated as follows, for predicting users in user `cluster 1`:

```
NoPosts... Friends ...  postCluster0_ratio... postCluster4_ratio  cluster_label
 24     ...   89    ...       0.35         ...        0.3              1
 ...
 ...
 81     ...  161    ...       0.2          ...        0.15              0
 ...
 ...
```

when cluster_label is 1, it means that this user belongs to user cluster 1, when cluster_label is 0, it means that this user does not belong to cluster 1,and I'd like to by doing wald test to decide which predictors(from NoPosts, Frineds...postcluster0_ratio...) are significant for predicting users cluater label, but from

http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.wald_test.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.wald_test
there are no examples for wald_test in python, I do not know what is the required input for wald_test, how to fit, in one word, I do not know how to use wald_test for my case, could you please help me how to use wald_test, it is better for providing me the code

Comment: This question is more about how to do a Wald test than about Python, isn't it? You'll get more help on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: FYI, apparently "there are several reasons to prefer the likelihood ratio test or the Lagrange multiplier to the Wald test"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Alternatives_to_the_Wald_test

Comment: To Jean-Francois Corbett, could you please provide me the code how to use wald_test,thank you

Comment: I cannot, because I do not know how the Wald test works. I wouldn't know how to do it with pen and paper. But the problem seems to be, neither do you. So in your place, that would be the first thing I would work on. Worry about the Python implementation later.

Answer (score 0):

For individual tests (not joint hypothesis) you can use the t_test which is a special case of the Wald test http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.t_test.html

The pvalues for the tests whether the parameters are statistically significant from zero are in `summary()` and are precomputed, see `pvalues` in http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html

`wald_test` is the more general version of the `f_test` for joint hypothesis which has some examples that work in the same way for wald_test
http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.f_test.html

Comment: The OP was asking about logistic regression, not linear regression.

Comment: @Yaniv  Logit and other models have the same t_test and wald_test method. Those methods are inherited by almost all models and just uses OLS in the docstring examples.